# Save blank data in database using material design form using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, material-design

I've used material design form in html and I set `EnableEventValidation=false` after click `save` button to save data in sql server, however there is a blank data saved in sql server

```
<div class="form">
    <h1>Patient Information</h1>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="Fname" required="required" />
        <label for="input" class="control-label">First Name</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="Lname" required="required" />
        <label for="input" class="control-label">Last Name</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="Address" required="required" />
        <label for="input" class="control-label">Address</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="city" required="required" />
        <label for="input" class="control-label">City</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select runat="server" id="gender">
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
        </select>
        <label for="select" class="control-label">Gender</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label-input100" for="date">Date Of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" id="birth" runat="server" name="datePurchase" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="ssec" required="required" />
        <label for="input" class="control-label">Social Security</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select runat="server" id="inppSel">
        </select>
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" style="color: red;" id="inpTxt" />
        <label for="select" class="control-label">Patient Case</label><i class="bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button onserverclick="save" type="submit" class="button" id="addnew" runat="server"><span>Submit</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

C#:

```
DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection();
db.disconnect();

string sql1 = "INSERT INTO TBL_Persons VALUES( @First_Name, @Last_Name, @Address, @City)";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, db.connect());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", Fname.Value);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Lname.Value);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Value);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city.Value);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

string sql2 = "INSERT INTO TBL_Patients VALUES(@Gender, @Date_OF_Birth, @Social_Security, @Person_ID, @Case_ID)";
db.disconnect();

string sql3 = "SELECT MAX(Person_ID) FROM TBL_Persons ";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql3, db.connect());
int max = (int)(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
db.disconnect();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql2, db.connect());
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender.Items[gender.SelectedIndex].Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_OF_Birth", birth.Value);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Social_Security", ssec.Value);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Person_ID", max);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_ID", inpTxt.Value);

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Done any debugging?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using Visual Studio? Are you able to set any breakpoints and trace this code. It would also help if you could show the code you use to call the C# method.

Comment: yes i use visual studio

Comment: I might be off here but as far my understanding goes, Material Design is a CSS thing styling the page. As such, it has **nothing** to do with the actual data or I/O-operations. Asking how to save Material Design form is like asking how to multiply blue number by a green number. It makes no sense in my head. Would you be able to elaborate? Or, perhaps, strip down the problem to a core issue exposing the actual hick-up, omitting the irrelevant parts? Also, the naming suggests that it's autogenerated code. What tool has been used for that?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...